# Dictionary search through Values with FirstOrDefault and direct increment does not compile

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, increment

we're trying to improve our code a bit and are wondering about some behaviour of the C# compiler / visual studio error.

Long story short, here's some sample code to reproduce the behaviour:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<int?, DictObject> testDict;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testObject = new DictObject { SearchIndex = "TestSearch2", Counter = 0 };

            testDict = new Dictionary<int?, DictObject>
            {
                { 0, testObject }
            };

            //works            
            var testKey = testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch")).Key;
            if (testKey != null) testDict[testKey].Counter++;

            //does not work. Exception "Value is null" (okay, that's expected).
            testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch")).Value.Counter++;

            //solution with ? operator -> or not ?!
            //compiler error: "the operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, propery or indexer.
            testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch")).Value?.Counter++;
        }
    }

    public class DictObject
    {
        public string SearchIndex { get; set; }
        public int Counter { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Additionally,

```
    testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch"))?.Value.Counter++;
```

does not work as well: "The ? Operator cannot be applied to operand of type KeyValuePair"

Could you please advise where our error is? Is there a possibility to write the dictionary firstordefault increment statement in a single line?

Thanks in advance, 
Martin

Comment: This is because you have `?.` the compiler doesn't know what to do when you'd do `null++`

Comment: Given the fact that FirstOrDefault() is never going to return you a null because it returns a struct in this case, I wonder how you are ever going to figure out if you found any matching value or not?

Comment: @TanveerBadar: But it does. Try to execute above code, in the second             testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch")).Value.Counter++; you'll get an error that Value is null.

Comment: Which is entirely different, KVP itself is never null. Your approach is ill-thought out. The default KVP it returns has a value which is null. You'll never know if you found the object you were looking for or not.

Comment: side observation: using `FirstOrDefault` to look in a dictionary is far from optimal; as long as this isn't the *primary* use of the dictionary, fine I guess

Comment: @MarcGravell How would you search the `Dictionary` values? Or are you suggesting the entire use of `Dictionary` may be incorrect? Depends on what the key represents, I suppose.

Comment: You could replace the `Value` property with a `public int` field, then you could have an extension method that increments a reference to an int, then you could have `Value?.Counter.Inc()` but this begins to feel like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps explain why you are using a `Dictionary` in such an unusual way? Perhaps what you really want is auto-vivification?

Comment: Also, LINQ is for _querying_ - you shouldn't be doing operations with side effects in a LINQ expression. See [Eric's article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/).

Comment: @NetMage usually, the way to query a dictionary is via key equality, that being what it is optimized as O(1) to do. Yes, you *can* sweep the data for O(N), but it might often mean that you've missed a trick.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix is probably to add a step:

```cs
var obj = testDict.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.SearchIndex.Equals("TestSearch")).Value;
if (obj != null) obj.Counter++;
```

Comment: That's a solution, but not really better than our "get a key, check if key is not null and then access dict with key". A single - line solution would be nice - but i doubt there is no. We're wondering if the ++ operator has issue with nullable types ...

Comment: For future readers: Don't! A dictionary does not have a concept of First/Last element, be warned! In this specific example, If your value is a value type, you are screwed. Compiler will only warn that you should not compare it to null but what you will get is a copy of the default object FirstOrDefault() returned. Mutating that will have no lasting effect, in short a bug. And if you have managed to screw up this far, you likely don't have any test cases either to catch this.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I will agree with you that perhaps `Single[OrDefault]` is a better fit here, but `First[OrDefault]` is fine *if we accept the premise that there will be at most one match* (and thus order is irrelevant) and we want to break early; as for the value-type bit: you're right, but in the example shown it is clearly a `class`. Frankly, the better advice there is simply "no mutable structs" - then it fails correctly at the `.Counter++` point

Comment: @NetMage I was responding to another comment that stated "If your value is a value type, you are screwed."